# How to ignore NA when selecting values from a vector in R

Tags: r

Say I have

```
a <- c(0:3, NA)
```

and I wish to replace 0 with 1 and replace 1 with 0. Namely, I want `a <- c(1, 0, 2, 3, NA)`. The following codes do not work because of `NA`

```
> a[a<2] <- 1- a[a<2]
Error in a[a < 2] <- 1 - a[a < 2] : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
```

I know we can use `na.rm = T` if we are using a function. How to add such argument in my case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just subset the values 0 and 1 using `%in%` and subtract from 1 - `%in%` returns FALSE for `NA` values and only TRUE for the values that match the rhs, then we subtract 1 so that 1-1 = 0 and and 1-0 = 1

```
a[a %in% 0:1] <- 1 - a[a %in% 0:1]
```

-output

```
> a
[1]  1  0  2  3 NA
```

---

Or if we want to use the OP's code

```
a[a < 2 & !is.na(a)] <- 1 - a[a < 2 & !is.na(a)]
```

Comment: Wonderful. Will accept as the answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately this is terribly cryptic code: be honest, who would understand that this code is written specifically to handle NAs? Not even experts necessarily think of that. The semantics of code (especially when surprising, such as when handling NAs) should be *explicit* to ensure maintainability.

Comment: @KonradRudolph this is used in the data cleaning stage where the 0s and 1s shall be switched. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Z. Yes but data cleaning should *also* be readable code. You will hate your former self if you ever come back to this code in two years and no longer remember what is going on here. Trust me, I’ve been there. Clever code is bad code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree. Although I don't expect a second person would read my codes, do you have another way of doing it?

Comment: For code readability, just add a comment that this particular solution is used because it handles `NA`s. You could even reference this SO question.

Comment: @jblood94 A comment is certainly better than nothing; but writing explicit code beats adding explanatory comments (that said, I do use plenty of comments, but first I try to make the code as self-explanatory as possible).

Comment: @KonradRudolph That works as well! Thanks for providing another approach!

Comment: `a[na.omit(a < 2)] = 1 - a[na.omit(a < 2)]` only works if the NAs are at the end of the vector. Try it with `a <- c(NA, 0:3, NA)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I wouldn't say it is that cryptic compared with an APL code ` f1 ← {⍺⍺ ( ⍵⍵ ⌷⍨∘⊂ ⍳ ) @ ( ∊∘⍺⍺ ) ⍵}` `(0 1 f1 1 0 ) a``#1 0 2 3`

Comment: @akrun To give a straight answer: *I actually don't know!* I do not know APL so I cannot judge how cryptic that code is to somebody who knows APL. I *do* know R, so I *can* judge the above code. Likewise, I don't know Chinese so I couldn't judge whether a given Chinese text is an easy to follow recipe or a riddle. I *can* judge in English.